# Prevent writing a lot of duplicate code in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, copy-paste

I have XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="Param 1 name" Margin="6,6,0,0"></TextBlock>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Param1Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="6,6,0,0"></TextBox>

<TextBlock Text="Param 2 name" Margin="6,6,0,0"></TextBlock>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Param2Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="6,6,0,0"></TextBox>

...

<TextBlock Text="Param N name" Margin="6,6,0,0"></TextBlock>
<TextBox Text="{Binding ParamNValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="6,6,0,0"></TextBox>
```

How can be optimized this code to prevent copy-paste?
Control, Style, ContentControl or DataTemplate?

I can use Style to reuse margin, but how can be reused structure of this pairs TexBlock and TextBox?

Comment: The title of this question is misleading; at first I thought it was about disabling Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V on the controls. Instead you wanted to prevent writing a lot of duplicate code. Could you please change the title into something more fitting, so others looking for a similar answer might find this more easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a UserControl with two properties (E.g., Caption and Text) and bind the TextBlock to the Caption and the TextBox to the Text property.

You could also use a Templated Control if you want to allow the designer to create a custom templates so he can fully control the UI design.

[UserControl vs. Custom/Templated Control](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/281e0eb1-cd50-4282-ba9a-07fc9f19d614/) (read the entire thread for maximum benefit):

> Well the difference between user control and custom control is that If
>   you have a portion of views or UI which will be used repeatedly in
>   your own project, using UserControl is a much simpler and preferred
>   way, but if you have a portion of UI and functionality which you
>   believe will be used aross different projects, then using custom
>   control is the right approach.

Answer (score 2):

May be you should try an [ItemsControl Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) and set it's `DataTemplate`.